# How to use two multiple file upload control files in a single button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using two file upload control in a page and save the files into a submit button click.

```
 For Single Uplaod -
      <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" class="form-control" runat="server" />
 For Multiple Upload -    
     <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload2" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" runat="server" />
```

In Submit Button Click i am using the code for Single Uplaod is

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
        FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
```

for Multiple Upload code is

```
    HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
            savepath = Server.MapPath(filepath);
            for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                {
.....
    }}
```

But `HttpFileCollection` take both the files of `FileUpload1` and `FileUplaod2`. How Can I select files of only `FileUplaod2`.

Can any one give a solution for this issue.

Comment: IList<HttpPostedFile> collection = FileUpload2.PostedFiles;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Request.Files`. It contains all files from `FileUpload1` and `FileUpload2`. Use `FileUpload2.PostedFiles` instead.

Here's an example usage

```
protected void uploadFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload2.HasFiles)
        {
            foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in FileUpload2.PostedFiles)
            {
                uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/MyPath/"),
                uploadedFile.FileName));
                listofuploadedfiles.Text += String.Format("{0}<br />", uploadedFile.FileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only use FileUpload2.PostedFiles in .net 4.5 and not anything below. Plus you wouldn't use multiple="multiple" in 4.5.. you would have to use AllowMultiple="true"